# How to convert a big bytes object to a list of 32-bit integer values?

Tags: python, python-3.x, type-conversion

I have a `bytes` object with a length `n` in bytes that is a multiple of 4. I want to convert it to a list of `n/4` 32-bit integer values.

What is an efficient way to do that?

For example, convert `x` to `y`:

```
x = b'\x01\x02\x03\x04\xef\xbe\xad\xde'
y = [0x04030201, 0xdeadbeef]
```

UPDATE 1: Figured out this code. Is there a simpler way (one liner kind of solution)?

```
x = b'\x01\x02\x03\x04\xef\xbe\xad\xde'
ls = [x[n:(n+4)] for n in range(0, len(x), 4)]
y = []
for xx in [int.from_bytes(xx, 'little') for xx in ls]:
    y.append(xx)
```

UPDATE 2: I realized I can combine the two loops:

```
x = b'\x01\x02\x03\x04\xef\xbe\xad\xde'
y = [int.from_bytes(x[n:(n+4)], 'little') for n in range(0, len(x), 4)]
```

Is this as elegant as it gets?

Comment: you can slice bytes and bytearrays

Comment: @ScottHunter - here ya' go.

Answer (score 5):

You can use the `struct` module.

```
>>> x = b'\x01\x02\x03\x04\xef\xbe\xad\xde'
>>> from struct import unpack
>>> unpack(f'<{len(x)//4}I', x)
(67305985, 3735928559)
```

(The need to compute the exact number of integers to unpack, instead of being able to say "Give me as many integers as possible from `x`" is a bit annoying.)

Comment: It looks like they want little-endian. `>` is big-endian.

Comment: Oops, thought I'd checked that.

Comment: You can also use `struct.calcsize('<I')` in place of hardcoding `4` in the count calculation, but that's even more annoyingly verbose. Gimme `unpack('<*I', x)`, darn it! :)

Comment: @chepner you can use `array.array` basically, see my answer

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Ah, I always forget `array` exists :) The indefinite `*` count is one of the few things I miss from Perl.

Comment: Exactly the answer I was preparing to write, complete with f-string.

Answer (score 5):

Probably the easiest thing would be just to use an `array.array`, you want unsigned integers, so you want `"I"` as the type code:

```
>>> import array
>>> x = b'\x01\x02\x03\x04\xef\xbe\xad\xde'
>>> arr = array.array('I', x)
>>> arr
array('I', [67305985, 3735928559])
```

Note, it will use the native byte-order when initalized with `bytes`, but you can byteswap it if you want:

```
>>> arr.byteswap()
>>> arr
array('I', [16909060, 4022250974])
>>> arr.byteswap()
>>> arr
array('I', [67305985, 3735928559])
```

If the project warrents `numpy`, you can also use numpy easily, there you can specify the byte-order in the `dtype`, in this case, an unsigned integer is `u`, and you give it the size in bytes directly:

```
>>> np.frombuffer(x, dtype='<u4')
array([  67305985, 3735928559], dtype=uint32)
```

If you really need a `list` object (`array.array` objects are almost perfect substitutes, `np.ndarray` objects have a less compatible interface) you can trivially convert:

```
list(array.array('I', x))
```

Or for `numpy`:

```
np.frombuffer(x, dtype='<u4').tolist()
```

Note, `list(np.array())` should be avoided, because it gives you a `list` of numpy.uint32 objects (basically boxed primitive values, you say you want actual python `int` objects).

Comment: `'I'` is documented as Minimum size in bytes = 2 ... How confident are you that it's 4?

Comment: @KellyBundy I'm not, it's platform dependent

Answer (score 2):

Benchmark with your `bytes` multiplied by 10^5 (solutions adjusted so they all give a list as requested):

```
  8.6 ± 0.3 ms  juanpa_array
  9.0 ± 0.2 ms  Frank
  9.9 ± 0.2 ms  chepner
 45.5 ± 0.4 ms  Kelly
 59.1 ± 0.8 ms  Woodford
 65.2 ± 0.6 ms  ysap_original

Python: 3.11.4 (main, Sep  9 2023, 15:09:21) [GCC 13.2.1 20230801]
```

Script:

```py
def Kelly(x):
    return [a + 2**8 * b + 2**16 * c + 2**24 * d for a, b, c, d in zip(*[iter(x)] * 4)]


def ysap_original(x):
    return [int.from_bytes(x[n:(n+4)], 'little') for n in range(0, len(x), 4)]


def juanpa_array(x):
    return list(array.array('I', x))


def chepner(x):
    return list(unpack(f'<{len(x)//4}I', x))


def Frank(x):
    return np.frombuffer(x, dtype=np.uint32).tolist()


def Woodford(x):
    return [int.from_bytes(z, 'little') for z in grouper(x, 4)]

def grouper(iterable, n, *, incomplete='fill', fillvalue=None):
    "Collect data into non-overlapping fixed-length chunks or blocks."
    # grouper('ABCDEFG', 3, fillvalue='x') --> ABC DEF Gxx
    # grouper('ABCDEFG', 3, incomplete='strict') --> ABC DEF ValueError
    # grouper('ABCDEFG', 3, incomplete='ignore') --> ABC DEF
    args = [iter(iterable)] * n
    match incomplete:
        case 'fill':
            return itertools.zip_longest(*args, fillvalue=fillvalue)
        case 'strict':
            return zip(*args, strict=True)
        case 'ignore':
            return zip(*args)
        case _:
            raise ValueError('Expected fill, strict, or ignore')


funcs = [ysap_original, juanpa_array, chepner, Frank, Kelly, Woodford]

from timeit import timeit
from statistics import mean, stdev
import sys
import array
from struct import unpack
import numpy as np
import itertools
import random

x = b'\x01\x02\x03\x04\xef\xbe\xad\xde'

for f in funcs:
    print(f(x), f.__name__)

x *= 10**5

times = {f: [] for f in funcs}
def stats(f):
    ts = [t * 1e3 for t in sorted(times[f])[:5]]
    return f'{mean(ts):5.1f} ± {stdev(ts):3.1f} ms '
for _ in range(25):
    random.shuffle(funcs)
    for f in funcs:
        t = timeit(lambda: f(x), number=1)
        times[f].append(t)
for f in sorted(funcs, key=stats):
    print(stats(f), f.__name__)

print('\nPython:', sys.version)
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=jVXNjts2ED4W8FMM0oN-Iitre7cIjLpAm26CIkDQQ9AebEOgJNJWTZECSS3kXeyT9JJLcs8r9DHyNB2Skv82SGtAMDXkfDPfx5nR35-avdlK8eHDx9aw8csv370rKYO3lPN92EXzEeBPUdMqAUsCz2Eaxy8hhtwvJz_guvDr6TWuS2BSAUkgT6BI8LUScF81YbysDFWIuMZD19F6NBrZOHtNmkyqalMJwp_Eq4RJmZJ1lu8N1WG3FPNQPEfvBAJeGcNpELl4woZRRGxoeJUApwKhkpMwf7VENCQjSpEnrHilTeh2Ur8f_BYk0EVR71tsaSNc6k_dWkQtdiELfnzwQV-8uH48d3-Nae0unUXjeOUtYxYZdTL7hi7Q3CLn2TRKjXQBBpQ_pSyRaPlfEt1fKnNvldko2TY-kNPEIg42ey0k5zQBkUCc4PFC1g2nhi4CVnGOZOzfHeEtXbyTgvYJPHslOaeFgZIYgl5GgpBiLO-o4qRpKrFBv46WYxRmY7YoYyt2GjClnMtip9NnDub7QyLBz7-8-vX29RsMODuNGXRIZTz-CXAf8AC86bpvup4y0EZVhbkA-MPi3iol1f_GqTZCKnqO45yJ2mhYgK_uQUtX5MLt18QU2xMoL579FURT8BIfjSdXa8GMlFyn2D8Zl1jcWBCxDXgqz2EVXSD31L-K7TrSI_lji_fqKUJP-tsIF07ZxWlSofEoeBjcdg1WDS0dhSF8Yuti0BhLnrWicLKezYfkrI-ToTMT32OJH1rJoVew0G1ngKlqWhmo6kYq07_5HW2IwS6rMFa_W1MibFIlvRv1Jr3Xw9LFHVxVWxxA_RwYjom2bvZANLb5YDpc5mDAjEtZj0YdssyDVXc1wWeKzwyf61VH2arL6aoj5aoraYBUUCFmm9lp41VuFPZdyNywY2mWCVLTLIssaryAyVUc34xGlrDV8oHNYbmGc5xHNwusDjpkfWcbp7zBEp7QmTtv7HmNadMydHBLto6W85v1-nQWseDByhcaHc1v0gl7hH8-w4PT0tlmzlZrCByZ7DizpzfDVHOqpHqLg5HT0KXoC-xr9F2ymKu_0pCTOi_JHLweeAk5VYvJsT6HzFMcT1Qgk-goak_OgSewo_uF0yQ61XlQ6UJrvxmsxO_uQzrH4YElk-Ic1JUUkf-s9l_X4Sv7Lw)

Answer (score 1):

As long as we're playing this game, numpy can also do it:

```
>> import numpy as np
>> np.frombuffer(x, dtype=np.uint32)
array([  67305985, 3735928559], dtype=uint32)
```

This uses machine-endianness.

If you want to specify a specific endianness

```
np.frombuffer(x, dtype=np.dtype(np.uint32).newbyteorder('<'))
```

If your string is very long, this code has the slight advantage that it doesn't copy the string. It literally uses the string you give it as its backing buffer.  The resulting array is read-only.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [`itertools` recipe for `grouper`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes).

```py
import itertools

def grouper(iterable, n, *, incomplete='fill', fillvalue=None):
    "Collect data into non-overlapping fixed-length chunks or blocks."
    # grouper('ABCDEFG', 3, fillvalue='x') --> ABC DEF Gxx
    # grouper('ABCDEFG', 3, incomplete='strict') --> ABC DEF ValueError
    # grouper('ABCDEFG', 3, incomplete='ignore') --> ABC DEF
    args = [iter(iterable)] * n
    match incomplete:
        case 'fill':
            return itertools.zip_longest(*args, fillvalue=fillvalue)
        case 'strict':
            return zip(*args, strict=True)
        case 'ignore':
            return zip(*args)
        case _:
            raise ValueError('Expected fill, strict, or ignore')

x = b'\x01\x02\x03\x04\xef\xbe\xad\xde'
y = [int.from_bytes(z, 'little') for z in grouper(x, 4)]
assert y == [0x04030201, 0xdeadbeef]
```

Comment: In Python 3.12 there's `batched`: `[int.from_bytes(batch, 'little') for batch in batched(x, 4)]`.